# Why won't my Click-Once app install?

Tags: deployment, clickonce

I have an app I wrote in WPF, which I publish by right-clicking on the project in Visual Studio 2013. This produces a set of files which I zip up and make available for users to download and install.

This has been working fine for a while, but today a user told me that he can't install the latest version. It gets as far as the install dialog, then just hangs there. If you kill the install, the app doesn't show up in the list of installed programs, but in Task Manager, I can see that the app itself is actually running, but has **three** instances running. I can't kill any of these, and have to restart the machine.

He's using Windows 7 Home Premium if it makes any difference.

I've tried uninstalling the old version and restarting his machine several times, but it doesn't help. The app installed fine on my machine, and as far as I know, nothing has changed on his machine.

Any ideas what's gone wrong? Don't know if I missed out any important details. If so, please let me know and I'll fill them in.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps anyone, it turned out to be to do with the certificate. I thought I was using one, but his machine seemed to think I wasn't. We had to turn off UAC and then right-click the exe to unblock it. That got him going.

I'm fed up with Click-once. it's been nothing but trouble. I've been playing with InnoSetup, which works really well and doesn't have all these problems. It's also pretty easy to make the app update itself automatically without driving the users mad.

Hope this helps someone.